# What is the proper way to reuse a MongoDB connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am needing to reuse a MongoDB connection in multiple different files for my Electron app but am having an issue that I don't understand. This led me to create a module to handle this.

> db.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
require('dotenv').config();

let db;

function connect () {
  return MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_HOST}?authSource=${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {
    auth: {
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS
    },
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }).then(client => {
    db = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

function getDB () {
  return db;
}

module.exports = { connect, getDB };
```

I them required this in my main file which is one of the files it is needed in.

> app.js

```
const mongoDB = require(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/assets/js/db`));
let db;

app.on('ready', async () => {
  await mongoDB.connect();

  db = mongoDB.getDB();

  setTimeout(createWindow, 0);
});
```

This works and I can use it in the `createWindow` function. a few seconds after, the app load the `index.html` file along with the `index.js` file and creates the window. `index.js` is another file I need to use it in so I require it there as well.

> index.js

```
const mongoDB = require(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/js/db`));
const db = mongoDB.getDB();

console.log(db);
```

This results in db being `undefined`. Isn't the first require in `app.js` supposed to be cached?

Comment: What you're not showing is where app is created/initialized  It's possible that you might be calling `mongoDB.getDB()` in app before `mongoDB.connect` has returned.

Comment: Correction: You could be calling `mongoDB.getDB()` in index.js before `app.on('ready')` is invoked/completes

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't see how as `app.on('ready');` is the one that calls the `createWindow` function which is the one that loads `index.js`. Everything seems in order. I even setup a setTimeout just now for 60 seconds for the `index.js` code above. Same thing with `undefined` as expected.

Comment: `app.js` is the start script for the Electron app as I said above. It's in my package.js file as the `main`.